# How to Bind scrolled EventHendler using mvvm for CollectionView in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, collectionview

I am trying to select item from collectionview after scroll programmatically from viewmodel.
Provided sample works only when item is tapped(selected), but I need item to be selected when scroll is finished.

How to handle scrolled event from mvvm?

My sample page: https://github.com/Darkoshacy/CollectionViewMySample

Comment: Related: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5716

Comment: Which item do you want to select when you scroll to the special position?

Comment: I solved with nuget Behaviors.forms. I will add description and code soon.